# How to exclude certain domains from an npm proxy

Tags: proxy, npm

We use npm behind a company firewall and thus use proxy and https-proxy settings in the npm configuration. This works fine as long as all npm modules are loaded from an external registry. But as a matter of fact we also have internal modules on an internal github. The access to these modules must not use the proxy of course. My question is: Can I specify a list of domains in the npm configuration, for which the proxy should not be used? Something like the no_proxy environment variable in the unix shell?

Comment: There is a pull request pending for this https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/2873

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming your environment looks like this:

- Build server with internet access only over proxy: your.proxy.host:3128
- Local Nexus Registry: https://your.local.nexus.registry/nexus/content/groups/npm/

NPM must use local Nexus Registry. Configuration file: .npmrc

```
registry = https://your.local.nexus.registry/nexus/content/groups/npm/
```

You can tell npm to use a proxy by setting the environment variables

```
http_proxy=http://your.proxy.host:3128
https_proxy=http://your.proxy.host:3128
```

but then npm will also try to reach your (local) Nexus Registry using the proxy.

You need to have one of the latest npm Versions (npm 2.14.7 works fine) and set an additional environment variable to exclude your Nexus Registry from the proxy:

```
no_proxy=your.local.nexus.registry
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the "no_proxy" configuration with former version of npm ?

Comment: @DánielKis I also find with npm 3.10.10 that no_proxy is not working. I tried putting it in the npmrc file and also in the main system environment variables. How did you fix it in the end?

Comment: @MickeyPuri Im also interested!

Comment: I am using npm 5.6.0 and it seems setting environment variable "no_proxy" at windows OS NOT WORKING.

Comment: I believe in npm, it should be `noproxy`, no underscore.

Answer (score 21):

Since **NPM 6.4.1**, released on 2018-08-22, you can use the `noproxy` option, even with a custom registry configured.

#### Example :

- `npm config set registry "http://<my-npm-registry-host>:<registry-port>"`
- `npm config set proxy "http://<my-proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"`
- `npm config set https-proxy "http://<my-proxy-host>:<proxy-port>"`
- `npm config set noproxy "my-proxy-host"` (accepts pattern like **.domain*)

#### Check config :

- `npm config list`

#### References :

- [NPM doc for noproxy](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#noproxy)
- [NPM changelog](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/CHANGELOG.md#v641-2018-08-22)
- [NPM PR #46](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/46)

Comment: I couldn't get the `noproxy` option working even though I'm on *NPM 6.13*, so I looked at the code and used the `no_proxy` environment var instead. See https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/node_modules/request/lib/getProxyFromURI.js for additional info.

Comment: I got it working with noproxy on .npmrc, but it didn't accepted pattern like *.domain. Npm version 6.13.4. I have the no_proxy for the environment with the hostname of my private repo, but It wasn't working anyway

Comment: OK, maybe as said [there](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#noproxy), we can just use *a comma-separated string or an array of domain extensions*

Comment: Addendum: in .npmrc file, we used to be able to write "no-proxy: XX.XX.XX.XX" but when we upgraded from NodeJS 12.20.X to NodeJS 16.X.X, we discovered that now it's "noproxy: XX.XX.XX.XX" that works (no hyphen, no underscore)

Answer (score 5):

to exclude certain domains , you can add below lines in .npmrc

```
noproxy[]=.local.nexus
noproxy[]=.internal.npm.repo
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#noproxy

Answer (score 1):

As [adiesner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4186022/adiesner) indicated, you cannot set a `noproxy`/`no_proxy` in the `npm config`, so the only way to do this is via the environment variables:

```
npm config set registry "your.local.nexus.registry/nexus/content/groups/npm/"

export http_proxy="http://your.proxy.host:3128"
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export no_proxy="your.local.nexus.registry"
```

Comment: not sure about the `npm config` command, but you can certainly set `noproxy=` in the `.npmrc` file (yes, there is no underscore in the command as of this date; type `npm config ls -l` in the command line, which also shows the defaults for all non-manually set values - there is no `no_proxy`, but there is a `noproxy` option)

Comment: Documentation for the `noproxy` option : https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#noproxy

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ***cntlm*** you should configure the *NoProxy* option in the configuration file "/etc/cntlm.conf". For instance,

```
Username         your_user
Domain           UCI.CU
Password         your_password
Proxy            10.0.0.1:8080
Listen           3128
NoProxy          uci.cu, edu.cu, nexus.prod.uci.cu, localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*
```

Remember that you must restart cntlm: `sudo systemctl restart cntlm`

Answer (score 0):

For PowerShell, the commands are:

```
$Env:http_proxy = "http://your.proxy.host:3128"
$Env:https_proxy = "http://your.proxy.host:3128"
$Env:no_proxy = "..."
```